# When I write in my .csv file the data gets jumbled up

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I wanted to make a python program that can keep a record of how you jogged.
Here's the code:

```
import csv

track =  open("track.csv", 'r+', newline='')
reader = csv.reader(track, delimiter=',')
write = csv.writer(track)

def line(day, numRounds, stamina):
    line = [day + ',' + numRounds + ',' + stamina]
    return line

day = '1'
numRounds = '1'
stamina = 'low'

line = line(day, numRounds, stamina)
write.writerow(line)
```

My .csv files already has this typed in:

```
Day,Rounds,Stamina
```

And when I run my python program the .csv file becomes this:

```
"1,1,low"
Stamina
```

It is very weird as some of the code gets erased and the ''" are  added on its own, I can't even find a proper video to help me out. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the file with the header row, it should be enough to open the file in *append mode* and pass it to the writer

```
import csv

with open("track.csv", 'a', newline='') as track:
    write = csv.writer(track)

    day = '1'
    numRounds = '1'
    stamina = 'low'

    line = [day, numRounds, stamina]
    write.writerow(line)
```

You an pass a list to `writer.writerow` and it will handle adding the commas - it will also convert `day` and `numRounds` to `str` if they are `int`s.

Comment: What's the difference between append and write??, because it looks like the same format.

Comment: `write` truncates (deletes) an existing file before writing to it, append starts writing from the end of the file - see https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#open

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot!